# Property 'list' does not exist on type 'Database'

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to follow an *Angular2 Firebase* app [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xXQjcy8x9E?t=5m49s) and I am stuck on this error. It seems list method no longer exist in latest version and I am not able to get any clue to fix this error.

**firebase.service.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from "angularfire2/database-deprecated";

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseService {
    listings: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
    constructor(private af:AngularFireDatabase) { }

  getListings(){
      this.listings=this.af.database.list('/listings') as FirebaseListObservable<Listing[]>
      return this.listings;
  }
}

interface Listing{
  //declarations
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use it as,

```
getListings(){
   this.listings=this.af.list('/listings') as FirebaseListObservable<Listing[]>
   return this.listings;    
}
```